# How to get the Avg from a column of Time(7) datatype?

Tags: sql, sql-server

OK the issue is, I'm trying to figure out `time(7)` and do `AVG` function this is what i have so far and its not working.

```
SELECT AVG(Sunset) AS AverageSunset FROM Weather
```

[image: Time Images of my data]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't average times but you can average the seconds since midnight then use that to get the average time of day.

```
SELECT CAST(DATEADD(SECOND,AVG(DATEDIFF(SECOND, 0, SunSet)),0) AS TIME)
```

Comment: thank you i had no clue you could use seconds i was going about this all the wrong way

Comment: so on that note. how would i find out the earliest and latest the sun raises?

Comment: @MIkeSmith you can use `MIN` and `MAX` directly against a `Time` column. So just `SELECT MIN(Sunset), MAX(Sunset) ...` would work for those.